# Program to find the result of primitive recursive functions

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a program to solve the result of primitive recursive functions:

```
  1 --Basic functions------------------------------
  2
  3 --Zero function
  4 z :: Int -> Int
  5 z = \_ -> 0
  6
  7 --Successor function
  8 s :: Int -> Int
  9 s = \x -> (x + 1)
 10
 11 --Identity/Projection function generator
 12 idnm :: Int -> Int -> ([Int] -> Int)
 13 idnm n m = \(x:xs) -> ((x:xs) !! (m-1))
 14
 15 --Constructors--------------------------------
 16
 17 --Composition constructor
 18 cn :: ([Int] -> Int) -> [([Int] -> Int)] -> ([Int] -> Int)
 19 cn f [] = \(x:xs) -> f
 20 cn f (g:gs) = \(x:xs) -> (cn (f (g (x:xs))) gs)
```

these functions and constructors are defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function

The issue is with my attempt to create the compositon constructor, cn.  When it gets to the base case, f is no longer a partial application, but a result of the function.  Yet the function expects a function as the first argument.  How can I deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There's also a function composition operator http://tinyurl.com/ykts2pz and an article on how to write pointfree code http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

Comment: Just a note: in `idnm`, you needlessly pattern-match against the `:` list constructor.  You can just write `idnm n m = \xs -> xs !! (m-1)`, with the `!!` operator forcing the list type; this simplifies to `idnm _ m = (!! (m-1))`.  If you really want to pattern-match against `:` (perhaps to forbid `[]`), you could write `idnm _ m xs@(_:_) = xs !! (m-1)`.

Comment: Well, all 3 functions are over complicated. `z = const 0; s = succ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given f,

```
f :: [a] -> b
```

and g_k,

```
g_k :: [a] -> a
```

we want to produce h,

```
h :: [a] -> b
```

so the composition should be like

```
compo :: ([a] -> b) -> [[a] -> a] -> [a] -> b
compo f gs xs = f (map ($ xs) gs)
```

Example: http://codepad.org/aGIKi8dF

---

Edit: It can also be written in applicative style (eliminating that `$`) as

```
compo f gs xs = f (gs <*> pure xs)
```